# iOS Autolayout Parallax Header

Tags: ios, autolayout, parallax

I followed an online tutorial to create Parallax Header using Autolayout only.

I was able to make some tweak to it
Here's the source code: https://github.com/vuvan01/ParrallaxHeader

When I swipe up and the top layout guide reaches the Button, the label keep scrolling, but the image view is kept there with smaller height. Plz check attached gif for illustration :[gif](http://g.recordit.co/hOAtzSMpSb.gif)

But I don't really understand why effect is like that. Can anyone please explain this to me?

Comment: Did you set an actual background color to your scroll view?

Comment: no, it's transparent

Comment: Set it with background color white. The parallax is supposed to do exactly that, but with an opaque view that passes on top of the image.

Comment: But my question is that why the Image View is kept at the top with smaller height. What decide the height of the Image View?

Comment: It's the image itself (it just keeps proportion). It's wider than the screen and when the width equals the screen one, it just "stays there".

Comment: oh i see, u'r right